# integral of complex function on symmetrical path

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Hi everyone I have a question concerning the solution of the following exercise:

Evaluate the integral of function $f(z)=\frac{Re(z)}{z^2+1}$ over the triangular path $\Gamma$ given by:

$\Gamma_1$: the segment of the x-axis between $-1,1$

$\Gamma_2 \Gamma_3$: the two segments connecting the edges of $\Gamma_1$ to the point $x=0,y=3/2$.

Beeing $f(z)= -f(-z)$ its integral over $\Gamma_1$ is $0$. Then I noticed that $\Gamma_4 = \Gamma_2 + \Gamma_3$ is also symmetrical with respect to the y-axis. Am I allowed to conclude that whatever the value of $\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)dz$ is the equality

$\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)dz = - \int_{\Gamma_2}f(z)dz$

holds?

If so, than I can conclude that

$\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz = 0$

Given that this approach is wrong (thanks for the suggestion) I have been trying to evaluate the integral:

on $\Gamma_2$ i get

$z = t + i (3/2 - 3/2t);$ $dz = (1-3/2i)dt;$ $f(z)= \frac{t}{(t(1-3/2i)+3/2i)^2+1};$ $t\in[0,1]$

hence

$(1-3/2i)\int_0^{1}\frac{t}{(t(1-3/2i)+3/2i)^2+1}dt$

which can be rewritten as

$\frac{1}{(1-3/2i)}\int_0^{1}\frac{t}{(t+\frac{3/2i}{(1-3/2i)})^2+\frac{1}{(1-3/2i)^2}}dt$

now I can substitute $u = t+\frac{3/2i}{(1-3/2i)}$ and obtain a sum of two terms which in the end are a $ln$ and a $arctan$. As for the $\Gamma_3$ part, this should be similar

I am not sure tho, this is the best way to come to a conclusion.

Comment: No. The symmetry of $f$ is with respect to zero and $\Gamma_1$ is symmertical with respect to zero, so $\int_{\Gamma_1} f=0$. But $\Gamma_4$ is not symmetrical about zero.

Comment: @FengShao thanks... I'll move forward with the actual computation of the integral :)

Comment: The residue fheorem shows that $\int_\Gamma \frac{z}{z^2+1}dz = \pi i$, but I don't know whether this helps.

Comment: Hi @PaulFrost, thanks for the hint. Considering that I am supposed to solve this exercise with the definition of complex integral (it is placed at a point in my text book where I haven't read anything about the residue theorem) I am not sure about that as well

Comment: In that case you have to compute certain integrals. However, be aware that your substitution does not work because it is not a map from $[0,1]$ to a real interval.